# Lookup activity output in array

Tags: azure-data-factory, lookup, azure-notebooks

i have a lookup activity in ADF which retrieves data from table like below
{
"count": 1,
"value": [
{
"Notebook_path": "/Users/Name@work.com/Project/ingestion/Cust1/ADT"
}
],
"effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (um)",
"billingReference": {
"activityType": "PipelineActivity",
"billableDuration": [
{
"meterType": "AzureIR",
"duration": 0.016666666666666666,
"unit": "DIUHours"
}
]
},
"durationInQueue": {
"integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
}
}

now i want to use the Notebook_path from above results and pass it to a Notebook activity to run that particular notebook as in the output, from lookup activity.

since its in array its creating problems . would appreciate some help here .

tried a lot of things but dint help.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have a similar lookup output. The following is a reference image of the same.

[image]

- You can use the following dynamic content to get the desired result.

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0]['notebook_path']
```

[image]

- My pipeline failed because I don't have a notebook, but you can see that the activity is trying to access the required path.

[image]

Comment: Saideep, buddy u r awesome .............! i was scratching my head from 2 days.
i reached till @activity('Lookup1').output.value[0] i could not figure out the rest.
thanks so much buddy. ill bug u again if i have more to learn :)_